# Repeating feature labels

Tags: qgis, labeling, repeating

I believe this should be a very simple task, but I'm struggling with why it's not working - I'm simply applying street name labels to line features, I want the labels to repeat every 2000m.  I've gone into the label settings > placement > and set the repeat value to 2000; but I'm still only getting a single label at the beginning of the feature (this feature in particular is 5950m)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check that your map and layer are both in the same coordinate reference system, and that it is one whose linear unit is Meter.

Comment: did you group the features?

Comment: Thanks - both map and layer were in the same coordinate system.  I took the easy solution and just split the feature into multiple parts so each was labelled.  Not ideal, but served its purpose.  Thanks for the replies.